# lua Printing specific key/value pairs in table

Tags: lua

I have an external lua table that is structured as follows:

```
sgeT = {
  [2535047] = {
  {
      ["account"] = "TG-MCB110105",
      ["exec"] = "/share/home/00288/tg455591/NAMD_2.8b3/NAMD_2.8b3_Linux-x86_64-MVAPICH-Intel-Ranger/namd2",
      ["execEpoch"] = 1305825864,
      ["execModify"] = "Thu May 19 12:24:24 2011",
      ["execType"] = "user:binary",
      ["jobID"] = "2535047",
      ["numCores"] = "128",
      ["numNodes"] = "8",
      pkgT = {
      },
      ["runTime"] = "65125",
      ["sha1"] = "e157dd510a7be4d775d6ceb271373ea24e7f9559",
      sizeT = {
         ["bss"] = "104552",
         ["data"] = "192168",
         ["text"] = "10650813",
      },
      ["startEpoch"] = "1335843433",
      ["startTime"] = "Mon Apr 30 22:37:13 2012",
      ["user"] = "guo",
      },
  },
  [2535094] = {
  {
     ["account"] = "TG-MCB110105",
     ["exec"] = "/share/home/00288/tg455591/NAMD_2.8b3/NAMD_2.8b3_Linux-x86_64-MVAPICH-Intel-Ranger/namd2",
     ["execEpoch"] = 1305825864,
     ["execModify"] = "Thu May 19 12:24:24 2011",
     ["execType"] = "user:binary",
     ["jobID"] = "2535094",
     ["numCores"] = "128",
     ["numNodes"] = "8",
     pkgT = {
     },
     ["runTime"] = "81635",
     ["sha1"] = "e157dd510a7be4d775d6ceb271373ea24e7f9559",
     sizeT = {
        ["bss"] = "104552",
        ["data"] = "192168",
        ["text"] = "10650813",
     },
     ["startEpoch"] = "1335823028",
     ["startTime"] = "Mon Apr 30 16:57:08 2012",
     ["user"] = "guo",
     },
  },
```

I am trying to use the following lua script to print the exec key/value pair as follows:

```
function DeepPrint (e)
   if type(e) == "table" then
       for k,v in pairs(e) do 
          if k == "exec" then
            print(k)
            DeepPrint(v)       
          end
       end
   else 
    print(e)
   end
 end


FileStr = "lariatData-sgeT-2012-05-01_2.lua"
Hnd, ErrStr = io.open(FileStr, "r")
if Hnd then
    dofile(FileStr)
    for Str in Hnd:lines() do       
        DeepPrint(sgeT)            
    end
Hnd.close()
else
    print(ErrStr, "\n")
end
```

Ideally, I would like to print the numerical indices and exec values, such as:

```
2535047 execVal
```

However, nothing returns when I run the code.  Originally the numerical indices were not enclosed in square brackets, but I added them to enable the file to be read.  However, given that they are not sequential, I cannot loop through them like an array, yet I believe that these numerical indices may be the source of my problems.  I am not sure what is wrong with the code I have, but it returns nothing.  Can anyone recommend how I can fix the code so that I can get the appropriate keys and values to return?   Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4):

Since your table has a fixed structure, you can simply use the syntactical sugar `sgeT[key1][key2]` to access `exec` key.

```
for i, v in pairs( sgeT ) do
  print( i, v[1].exec )
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over lines in the file, but you already processed and loaded that file (as a Lua chunk), so it's no longer needed. Just do this:

```
dofile(FileStr)
DeepPrint(sgeT)
```

The main issue is that you only call `DeepPrint` recursively for those keys that have value `exec`, but none of the keys at the first level do (so nothing gets printed as you didn't go beyond the first level). You probably need to close `if` before calling `DeepPrint`:

```
function DeepPrint (e)
   if type(e) == "table" then
       for k,v in pairs(e) do 
          if k == "exec" then
            print(k)
          end
          DeepPrint(v)       
       end
   else 
    print(e)
   end
 end
```